# Compare 2 array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have 2 arrays of similar element but arranged in different order.
I have a source variable with is arranged according to `arr1` based on key `src` and file of `arr1` and source.
Now i want to arranged destination variable according to `arr2`.
Could you please let me know how we can done with lodash?

```
arr1 = [{x:0,y:1,src:a1},{x:1,y:1,src:b1},{x:2,y:1,src:c1}]

arr2 = [{x:1,y:1,src:b1},{x:1,y:1,src:a1},{x:1,y:1,src:c1}]

source = [{file:a1},{file:b1},{file:c1}]
Destination = [{file:b1},{file:a1},{file:c1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use lodash's map routine to achieve this:

```
let source = [{
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  src: 'b1'
}, {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  src: 'a1'
}, {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  src: 'c1'
}]

let destination = _.map(source, value => {
    return { file: value['src']}
})
```

See here for an [example](https://repl.it/@8enSmith/RespectfulThoughtfulInsect).

Also note that you can achieve this using the standard [JavaScript map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.